# GitLab reconfigure Error: executing action `create` on resource 'user[git]'

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried to install Gitlab `gitlab_7.4.3-omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1_amd64.deb` on my server.

And there is an error when I ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

The is the error `log`:

```
[2014-11-07T12:26:33+08:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-11-07T12:26:33+08:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.2 ***
[2014-11-07T12:26:33+08:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 17502
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[gitlab]"] from CLI options
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[gitlab]]
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Run List expands to [gitlab]
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for R710
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/gitlab] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/gitlab]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:40:in `from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/gitlab]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/users.rb:23:in `from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Previous directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-rails.rb:37:in `block in from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Current  directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/definitions/unicorn_config.rb:21:in `block in from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[unicorn] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Previous service[unicorn]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:64:in `block in from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Current  service[unicorn]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:191:in `block in from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[sidekiq] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Previous service[sidekiq]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:64:in `block in from_file'
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] WARN: Current  service[sidekiq]: /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:191:in `block in from_file'

================================================================================
[31mError executing action `create` on resource 'user[git]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '8'
---- Begin output of ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab", "git"] ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: usermod: user git is currently logged in
---- End output of ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab", "git"] ----
Ran ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab", "git"] returned 8


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/users.rb

 34: user gitlab_username do
 35:   shell node['gitlab']['user']['shell']
 36:   home gitlab_home
 37:   uid node['gitlab']['user']['uid']
 38:   gid gitlab_group
 39:   system true
 40: end
 41:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/users.rb:34:in `from_file'

user("git") do
  action :create
  supports {:manage_home=>false, :non_unique=>false}
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  username "git"
  gid 1014
  home "/var/opt/gitlab"
  shell "/bin/sh"
  system true
  cookbook_name :gitlab
  recipe_name "users"
end



[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-11-07T12:26:35+08:00] ERROR: user[git] (gitlab::users line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '8'
---- Begin output of ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab", "git"] ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: usermod: user git is currently logged in
---- End output of ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab", "git"] ----
Ran ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/sh", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab", "git"] returned 8
[2014-11-07T12:26:36+08:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Something else is:

I saw `usermod: user git is currently logged in` in my log. And I already have a user on my server named `git` . So is there any problem, and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The fact that you already have a user named `git` is likely to be the problem: you will need a user reserved for GitLab.

Have you tried to do [as explained on the README](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/54050a5d020fb8de5a10573324ecdd82e325c4f3/README.md#changing-the-name-of-the-git-user-group):

By default, omnibus-gitlab uses the user name `git` for Git gitlab-shell login,
ownership of the Git data itself, and SSH URL generation on the web interface.
Similarly, `git` group is used for group ownership of the Git data.  You can
change the user and group by adding the following lines to
`/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

```
user['username'] = "gitlab"
user['group'] = "gitlab"
```

Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.

Comment: Cool!! I didnt notice that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! it working after painful trial and error. In my cases i have to recreate this ..
      sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
( i am running ubuntu 14.04 on my vm)

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is right , you've already a git user. This can be because you already create it or because your gitlab installation is running. If this is the case , you'll be creating a new user not need it.

Try :

```
sudo service gitlab stop
```

and Run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

for the change to take effect.